# How do I create a new image with [node] graphicsmagick using toBuffer

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to create a new image which will eventually be insert into a mongo database via gridfs. I'd prefer to avoid writing anything to the filesystem so the best route seems to [create a new image](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm#basic-usage), write the result to a buffer, then insert the buffer into the database. Unfortunately, the [toBuffer method](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm#buffers) doesn't work for new images:

```
var gm = require( 'gm' );
gm(200, 200, '#000F')
    .setFormat('png')
    .fill('black')
    .drawCircle( 50, 50, 60, 60 )
    .toBuffer( 'PNG', function( error, buffer )
    {
        if( error ) { console.log( error ); return; }
        console.log( 'success: ' + buffer.length );
    }
);
```

... yeilds the following error:

> [Error: Stream yields empty buffer]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like gm simply doesn't like the `'PNG'` argument you're giving to `toBuffer`. I don't think its necessary either since you've already specified the format as png earlier on. Try simply removing it:

```
var gm = require( 'gm' );
gm(200, 200, '#000F')
    .setFormat('png')
    .fill('black')
    .drawCircle( 50, 50, 60, 60 )
    .toBuffer(function( error, buffer )
    {
        if( error ) { console.log( error ); return; }
        console.log( 'success: ' + buffer.length );
    }
);
```